# Using / swapping a Collections.synchronizedList safely

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

In a multi threaded app we have a method that processes a list in a singleton. To get a snapshot of the list we do:

```
public List swapList() {
    if (syncLinkedList.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    List currentList = normalLinkList;
    normalLinkList = new LinkedList();//java.util.LinkedList.LinkedList()       
    syncLinkedList = Collections.synchronizedList(normalLinkList);
    return currentList;
}
```

One thread processes above singleton.

Another object receives requests on many threads that have sockets, adding new requests to the syncLinkedList, on many threads, like this:

```
syncLinkedList.add(obj);
```

Is this a safe way to swap a singleton?

Update on 11 July : 
Will items by in one of the two lists - currentList or the new normalLinkList ? As long as items are in one of these, we should be fine.

Comment: As an aside, you should really look into using [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: You can perform an atomic swap of your object using an `AtomicReference`. Ensuring the thread-safety of the content of the list during the process is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer **NO** your `swapList` is not tread-safe.

Some explanation: while it produce thread safe result the method `swapList` itself is not tread safe.

Easiest way to fix this is to mark it with `synchronized` modifier.

Comment: I think just synchronizing is overly simplistic. If a thread clears the list then gets halfway though adding elements when another thread decides to clear the list, you've got inconsistencies. You probably need some kind of read-write lock.

Comment: @Michael after list was returned from `swapList` no references to it is held by class. So no one can change it anymore.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the task. But I feel it is weird that some list `normalLinkList` is not thread safe and it will continue be used in parallel with synchronized version.

Comment: @ArtemPetrov It won't. It is replaced to new copy by `normalLinkList = new LinkedList()`. No reference to old copy except `currentList` is held and `currentList` is local variable.

Comment: @talex But `currentList` is returned from the method

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe.

When you're thinking about thread safety, always think in terms of two actions on different threads, and whether there is a formal [happens-before relationship](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) between them. That's not always enough for thread safety (depending on what you need to accomplish), but it's nearly always required. In this case, we have the following actions:

1. Thread A instantiates a new LinkedList and assigns it to normalLinkList
2. Thread A wraps this new list in a synchronizedList, and assigns that to syncLinkedList
3. Some thread presumably modifies the syncLinkedList; it doesn't matter which this is, so let's keep it on thread A for now. Breaking this down a bit:

   - Thread A acquires a lock on the syncLinkedList
   - Thread A modifies normalLinkList
   - Thread A releases the lock
4. Thread B reads normalLinkList into a temporary variable, currentList, and returns it
5. Thread B presumably reads from that list

That description is fairly high-level, but it's actually a bit more detail than we need. Let's take it down to the really bare essence:

1. Thread A instantiates a new LinkedList and assigns it to normalLinkList
2. Thread A modifies normalLinkList by:

   - acquiring a lock
   - modifying the list directly
   - releasing the lock
3. Thread B gets a reference to normalLinkList and accesses it

Note that thread B has not done anything whatsoever with the lock. This means that there is no happens-before relationship between it accessing the list, and any of the modifications that thread A. The relevant happens-before relationship for locks is:

> An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor.

... but since B doesn't ever acquire a lock, there is no happens-before. This is known as a data race, and it's why the [JavaDocs for Collections.synchronizedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) explicitly say:

> it is critical that **all** access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.

So, what should you do? Just what the JavaDocs say to do: only access the synchronizedList (never its backing list), and if you do anything that requires iterating over it, only do so while holding its lock.

The easiest thing would be to not swap at all, but rather to copy the contents to a new list and then clear out the synchronized one:

```
// Only do this once. And note, we don't even keep a reference
// to the underlying list. We only access it through syncLinkedList.
syncLinkedList = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
...

List readSnapshot;
synchronized (syncLinkedList) {
    readSnapshot = new LinkedList(syncLinkedList); // implicit iteration
    syncLinkedList.clear(); // prepare for next batch (while holding lock)
}
return readSnapshot;
```

It's important to call `clear()` while still holding the lock. Otherwise, if someone added to the list after you released the lock but before you cleared the list, that addition would be lost (since it's not in the snapshot, but it's cleared anyway).

Comment: thank you yes i will add the synchronized block. in all the IO code this will hardly have any impact.

Comment: but will this help if in the other places where we add new items with syncLinkedList.add() is not in a synchronized/ locked block?

Comment: When you say its unsafe, does it just mean some items maybe in the old list instead of the new one? We add from many threads, then when size is > x, we make a copy (swap) and process the old elements. So as long as no object from the list if lost, we are fine (will be either in new or old list)

Comment: No, it's worse and more complicated than that. Compiler reorderings will let you see really weird things if you don't prevent them via synchronization. For instance, you can see partially constructed objects. Search for that term, as well as data races. In short, nearly any assumption you have about code will be out the window. And no, if you don't use the lock on writes, it will not fix it. First of all, synchronizedList adds them for you. But even if it didn't, the whole problem is that you need the lock on both write and read.

Comment: Also, I should add that multithreading is very complex, and random, and so is pretty much impossible to learn by trial and error. I'd strongly recommend reading a book or in-depth tutorial. I learned initially from Java Concurrency In Practice.